# Magento 2 upload image not showing in post form data

Tags: magento2, forms, adminform, image-upload

I have created a custom module and in the admin  New/Edit form I added the image field but when I submit the form with uploading image, it won't show the image in save controller.

I used to add below code to add image field in admin from:

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'image',
        'image',
        array(
            'label' => __('Image'),
            'name'  => 'image',
            'class' =>'admin__control-image',
    )
 );
```

also in my form, I added the multipart form data as below:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post' , 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]
    );
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

How to get rid of this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'profile',
    'image',
    [
        'name' => 'profile',
        'label' => __('Profile Image'),
        'title' => __('Profile Image'),
        'required'  => false,
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

controller file save.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

$profileImage = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('profile');
$fileName = ($profileImage && array_key_exists('name', $profileImage)) ? $profileImage['name'] : null;
if ($profileImage && $fileName) {
    try {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
            ['fileId' => 'profile']
        );
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapterFactory */
        $imageAdapterFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')
            ->create();
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
            ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

        $result = $uploader->save(
            $mediaDirectory
                ->getAbsolutePath('Modulename/Profile')
        );
        //$data['profile'] = 'Modulename/Profile/'. $result['file'];
        $model->setProfile('Modulename/Profile'.$result['file']); //Database field name
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```